# If i use my web service in IIS-7 then in mysql it reuse the connection pool, but if I used it in IIS-6 then it is not reusing the pool

Tags: asp.net

If i use my web service in IIS-7 then in mysql it reuse the connection pool, but if I used it in IIS-6 then it is not reusing the pool and after some time giving connection pool error.
  why it is giving error.

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

Are you closing the connection properly using either a using statement or a try/finally?

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("string"))
{
     conn.Open();
     // your code here
}
```

or

```
MySqlConnection conn = null;
try
{
     conn = new MySqlConnection("string");
     conn.Open();
     // your code here
}
finally
{
     if (conn != null) { conn.Close(); }
}
```

Comment: yes i am closing all open connections in finally block,  but the error is still

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Are you disposing all you Command, DataReader etc objects as well?